# How to send a different payload from java component?

Tags: java, jms, mule

I have a mule flow that works with a JMS message and a Java component to handle a batch process. After finishing the job, I need to send an email to notify the user about the results of this process. I'm currently handling all this, processing and email sending, inside a Java component. I want to decouple the email send operation in order to reuse this component in other flows instead of copying/pasting/adapting the code from the Java component to other components. My problem is that the payload I want to send to this component is a `Map<String, Object>` while the flow receives a `Serializable` parameter (in this case, a custom class that extends `Serializable`). How can I change the payload before being sent from the Java component, where I know the parameters to set in this `Map<String, Object>` before calling the email component?

Currently this is what I have:

```xml
<flow name="SomeBatchProcessFlow">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="${some.batch.process}"
        connector-ref="JmsConnectorRef" />
    <component>
        <method-entry-point-resolver>
            <include-entry-point method="foo" />
        </method-entry-point-resolver>
        <spring-object bean="someBatchProcessComponent" />
    </component>
    <!--
        what to put here to change the payload for the Map<String, Object> I've prepared
        in SomeBatchProcessComponent#foo method?
    -->
    <jms:outbound-endpoint address="jms://${queues.emailSend}"
        connector-ref="JmsConnectorRef" />
</flow>

<flow name="EmailSendFlow">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="${queues.emailSend}"
        connector-ref="JmsConnectorRef" />
    <component>
        <method-entry-point-resolver>
            <include-entry-point method="sendEmail" />
        </method-entry-point-resolver>
        <spring-object bean="emailSenderComponent" />
    </component>
</flow>
```

I'm aware that I can manually send a JMS message from `SomeBatchProcessComponent#foo` but I would prefer that mule handle this work to keep it decoupled.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and stop using `component`+`method-entry-point-resolver`+`spring-object` and instead use a the `invoke` message processor. It's a single XML element that allows calling any method on any bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set payload in the mule flow use
`<set-payload value="#[newPayload]"/>` where `newPayload` is the local variable.

To change the payload in Java component, return a `Map<String, Object>` object and that will be pushed to `JMS`.

You may also look into `vm queues` instead of using JMS for email,

Comment: How then could I retrieve the returned `Map<String, Object>` in the mule flow to set it in the `<set-payload>`?

Comment: Your payload will itself be set to `Map<String, Object>` if component returns that.